# How to permanently disable kvm modules in Linux?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

In order to get virtualbox to work in Linux I have to run the following commands as root:

```
modprobe -r kvm_intel
modprobe -r kvm
```

otherwise I get an error. This works well.

The only problem is that I have to re-run those two commands every time the machine reboots.

Is there a way to permanently disable those two kernel modules?

Comment: updated my answer for fedora, plus you might look at the complete-disable option

Comment: I'm stuck trying to figure out how to stop the qemu-system service,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't plan to use kvm at all, why not simply remove the `qemu-system-[ARCH]` rpm that supplies it.  Also, fedora contains a file `/etc/sysconfig/modules/kvm.modules` which tells the system to load the kvm modules if virtualization extensions are detected in the processor.  Modifying `/etc/sysconfig/modules/kvm.modules` or removing it altogether should also solve the problem, but removing the package seems like it would be the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: For Fedora, save the `blacklist` lines under Option 1 below into a file under /etc/modprobe.d/, for example, `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`.  The name of the file isn't important; all files in the directory get processed during boot.

Option 3 might be more preferable if you're sure you'll never need to load these modules dynamically.

#### Option 1: Blacklist

Many distros use a module blacklist to disallow module loading.  Normally this can be done by adding these lines to your distro's `modules.conf` or similar.  You might try reading `man modules.conf` or googling for directions for your specific distribution.

```
blacklist kvm_intel
blacklist kvm
```

#### Option 2: Unload

An alternative is to add these lines to your `rc.local` script (or some other system boot-time script, preferably not one associated with a package):

```
modprobe -r kvm_intel
modprobe -r kvm
```

#### Option 3: Disable (new)

Both of the above will prevent the modules from getting loaded on bootup, but won't stop them from loading into the kernel later.  To **completely disable** the module, use these lines -- again, they can go in a `modules.conf` file, or in `/etc/modprobe.d/disabled` or similar:

```
install kvm_intel /bin/true
install kvm /bin/true
```

What this does is tell the system to run `/bin/true` whenever these modules are requested.  The program doesn't do anything except return true, so any load "succeeds" but the modules are never actually loaded.  To re-enable drivers disabled with this technique, comment out these lines and reboot.

Comment: Thanks. The rc.local tip should work. I am using Fedora which does not appear to have a modules.conf file, at least, none that 'locate' could find.

Comment: At least on CentOS the file name should be `/etc/modprobe.d/disabled.conf` (without `.conf` extension it won't be picked up).